# Two different ajax calls being linked together

Tags: jquery, ajax, history.js

I've got two ajax calls on the one page, but for some reason they are being linked together (after the first call). I've specified different classes for each ajax call to run on but still not working. I'm using the History.js plugin too. I think this may have something to do with it.

I've tried using different variables but no dice. I'm pretty new to ajax and any help would be much appreciated! See my code below, I've tried to simplify it, but the end result will be two different transitions for each section.

EDIT: made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwrw8uwh/3/)

The problems happens after the first click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function isCanvasSupported(){
var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}

// The action for the rusty rusty browsers  
if (!isCanvasSupported()) {}

var pushstate = 'push';

    if (!isCanvasSupported()) {
        pushstate = 'no';
    }

var projectClick = function(url) {

    if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function' && pushstate == 'push') {    

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",

            success : function(datam) {

                alert('project clicked')
            }
        });
    } 

    else {
        window.location.href = url;
    }

}

var mainNavClick = function(url) {

    if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function' && pushstate == 'push') {    

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",

            success : function(data) {

                alert('main nav clicked');
                console.log('clickd')

            }
        });
    } 

    else {
        window.location.href = url;
    }

}

    if (pushstate == 'push') {
    $('body').on('click', "#page-menu", function(e){    

        History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
            var State = History.getState();
            mainNavClick(State.url);
        });

        e.preventDefault();

        History.pushState({state:1,rand:Math.random()}, document.title, this.href);

    });



    $('body').on('click', ".to-project", function(e){   

        History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
            var State = History.getState();
            projectClick(State.url);
        });

        e.preventDefault();

        History.pushState({state:1,rand:Math.random()}, document.title, this.href);

    });

}
```

});

Comment: Please clarify "...being linked together." Do you mean they are both being called upon a single event, which do not want? Can you provide HTML as well? A JSFiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the HTML. You are using delegation for both click events on HTML body, so if some of those click events happen to have both `#page_menu a` and `.to-project` within the event bubbling hierarchy, it would fire both.

Comment: I click "#page-menu a", and mainNavClick() runs - that's all good. But if I click ".to-project" after clicking "#page-menu a", mainNavClick() runs again as well. And visa versa for the projectClick() function. 

I only want mainNavClick() to run when "#page-menu a" is clicked.
And I want projectClick to run when ".to-project" is clicked.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: JSFiddle here @Jason http://jsfiddle.net/bwrw8uwh/3/ Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Each time a user clicks ".to-project" you are binding an event to the History Adapter. Bound events remain until specifically removed and will fire when triggered. So if the user clicks three times, that means the event is bound three times and fires each one once. Do not bind the event on click; instead bind the event on page load.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me an example of how to rewrite the function? Will the history plugin still work if it's not bound to the click? Thanks again - much appreciated. @Jason